# Adding unique id attribute to img tag

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add a unique id attribute to each img tag while mapping so that i can use it for some logic else where
How can I do it?

```
const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      id={???}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
  ));
```

I want .map to add 0 to .. on each mapped img id

Comment: you can simply use the index or provide an incremental id in the image data when you create it

Comment: is the `img.id` value not unique enough? If it isn't, you could use the index value of the `.map` like this... `image.map((img, index) =>` then add the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the index number.

```
const imgs = image.map((img, index) => {
    <img
      id={index}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
});
```

Check the section List & Keys from React doc:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

And check how map method works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

```
const imgs = image.map((img, index) => {
    <img
      id={index}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
});
```

.map method will return the index starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but try to add an   index as a unique id like that:

```
image.map((img,index) => (
    <img
      id={index}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use index as tag id like `<img id={index} />`, but don't use index as img `key` because it is an [Anti Pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318),

Instead you can use plugins like [react-key-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index)

Assume you have an array of image src, you can make unique id for each array item using `react-key-index`:

```
import keyIndex from 'react-key-index';

const images = [
  "src1",
  "src2",
  "src3"
]

var output = keyIndex(images, 1);
```

The output will be like this:

```
// output
[
  {
    value: "src1",
    id: "kRf6c2fY"
  }, {
    value: "src2",
    id: "lYf5cGfM",
  }, {
    value: "src3",
    id: "mZfKcGf9"
  }
]
```

And now you can map it:

```
const imgs = output.map(img => (
    <img
      id={img.id}
      key={img.id}
      src={img.value}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
    />
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

if img here needs to have some logic then maybe make it a component of it's own so just a suggestion